# How to get the path to a file downloaded via a browser in Webdriver in Codeception?

Tags: php, selenium-webdriver, codeception, acceptance-testing

I do acceptance testing with Codeception using WebDriver. I have a button on my page which I can click to download a file. How do I then see the content of the downloads directory? I haven't found any configuration parameter to set up the downloads directory, or a method to access files from the downloads directory. Is it even available in Codeception?

Answer (score 2):

For Chrome, you can set the download directory in your `acceptance.suite.yml`:

```
modules:
    enabled:
        - WebDriver:
            browser: chrome
            capabilities:
                chromeOptions:
                    prefs:
                        download.default_directory: "C:/download"
```

Haven't tried for Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Path to downloads directory is configured with Selenium, it is not Codeception's job to provide access to downloaded files.